# Alternative to loader's this._compilation

Tags: javascript, webpack

The [docs say](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders#this_compilation) accessing `this._compilation` is hacky and it is even deprecated. I need it to access the output filename in particular:

```
this._compilation.outputOptions.filename
```

```
context._compilation.outputOptions.filename
```

What would be a future proof way of accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced with Webpack but I think your looking for the [Output](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) key.

If you scroll down in the manual (v4.35.3) you will see examples for [output.filename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename) that I think answer your question.

You might want to look at [output.path](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpath) farther down if your needing the full absolute path including the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not talking about webpack's configuration but the context passed to loaders. Does the question need clarification in this regard?

Comment: No I think your wording is fine I'm just not experienced enough with webpack to truly help. It appears (based on no other answers or comments) that SO is lacking devs who really know webpack.

Comment: Does the "A simple example" from this help: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/how-to-write-a-plugin#a-simple-example

Answer (score 0):

Even though [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8535) is not the definitive answer, I think it may be helpful to you.

As mentioned in the article,

> we can implement getHashOutputOptions and return all hash* options from compilation. No need to make the compilation public.